# Boltzmann constant in atomic units

Tags: thermodynamics, units, si-units

I was just wondering what value the Boltzmann constant $k_B$ takes when we are using Hartree atomic units (i.e $\hbar=e=a_0=m_e=1$) where the unit of energy is 1 hartree. Should we we convert $1.38 \times 10^{-23} \rm\: J\:K^{-1}$ to hartree/K if all our other units are expressed in atomic units?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should we we convert $1.38 \times 10^{-23} \rm\: J\:K^{-1}$ to Hartree/K if all our other units are expressed in atomic units?

In short, yes. The numerical value then becomes $k_B = 3.167 \times 10^{-6}\: E_\mathrm{H} / \rm K$. This gives the direct route to calculate products of the form $k_BT$ (with $T$ in kelvin) in hartrees, which then give direct values of energy in atomic units.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!